# RStudio does not start in Ubuntu 12.04: segmentation fault

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, rstudio

Whenever I start R-studio after having installed the  package  `rstudio-0.99.473-amd64.deb` the program quits instantly with a segmentation fault. The last output lines of `strace` are:

> strace rstudio

```
open("/var/cache/fontconfig/99e8ed0e538f840c565b6ed5dad60d56-le64.cache-3", O_RDONLY) = 21
fstat(21, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7224, ...}) = 0
close(21)                               = 0
stat("/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/var/cache/fontconfig/945677eb7aeaf62f1d50efc3fb3ec7d8-le64.cache-3", O_RDONLY) = 21
fstat(21, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=34128, ...}) = 0
close(21)                               = 0
stat("/usr/share/fonts/type1/mathml", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/var/cache/fontconfig/c05880de57d1f5e948fdfacc138775d9-le64.cache-3", O_RDONLY) = 21
fstat(21, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1472, ...}) = 0
close(21)                               = 0
stat("/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/large", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/var/cache/fontconfig/6333f38776742d18e214673cd2c24e34-le64.cache-3", O_RDONLY) = 21
fstat(21, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=112, ...}) = 0
read(21, "\4\374\2\374\3\0\0\0p\0\0\0\0\0\0\0008\0\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 112) = 112
close(21)                               = 0
brk(0xdac000)                           = 0xdac000
brk(0xdcd000)                           = 0xdcd000
brk(0xdee000)                           = 0xdee000
open("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-R.ttf", O_RDONLY) = 21
fcntl(21, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
fstat(21, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=353824, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 353824, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 21, 0) = 0x7f5ac4066000
close(21)                               = 0
brk(0xe10000)                           = 0xe10000
write(5, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
write(5, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
write(5, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"b0\3\0\3\0\2\0", 8}, {"GLX", 3}, {"\0", 1}], 3) = 12
futex(0x7fff735915c4, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL) = 0
futex(0xaaaa78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"\207\7\3\0\1\0\0\0\4\0\0\0", 12}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 12
futex(0x7fff735916a4, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL) = 0
futex(0xaaaa78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"b\7\6\0\17\0\0\0", 8}, {"ATIFGLEXTENSION", 15}, {"\0", 1}], 3) = 24
futex(0xaaaa78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"\207\23\3\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0", 12}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 12
futex(0x7fff73591654, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL) = 0
futex(0xaaaa78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"\207\23\3\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\0\0", 12}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 12
futex(0x7fff73591654, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL) = 0
futex(0xaaaa78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"\207\16\2\0\0\0\0\0", 8}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 8
futex(0x7fff735916a4, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0xaaaa78, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 0
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

R 3.2.2 is installed and works fine. I also installed Rstudio server and works ok.

Any ideas?